# ("IID_IColumnsInfo") error with SQL Server BULK INSERT of CSV file

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm new to SQL Server, so forgive me for being a bit of a noob here.

The code shown here returns the following error:

> Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Code:

```
BULK INSERT testingtable
FROM 'D:\TimeLords\data\db-test-file.csv'
WITH
    (FORMAT = 'CSV', 
     FIELDQUOTE = '"',
     FIRSTROW = 2,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',  
     TABLOCK)
```

I've tried using:

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
```

and

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
```

This is the CSV file: https://gyazo.com/0392b660c97e3cac27f2337993190c69

This is my SQL table: https://gyazo.com/fbbaf6204df9bb574d8887864cc95ea0

And this is the complete SQL query: https://gyazo.com/ffe020437f07524ce44420bedeebf0d4

I've scouted StackOverflow and can't find any solution which works. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a couple of example lines from the input `.csv` for us to test with? This works fine for me with a dummy csv file I created and a `testingtable` table which matched the columns in that csv.

Comment: Is this the ONLY code in your window?   The error suggests that it's trying to parse this as part of some other code.

Comment: Hi guys, I've added some more information - hopefully it helps. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: What version/edition of SQL Server are you using? This is still working fine for me here with a file and query which are visually identical to yours (albeit I removed the `FIRSTROW` argument, as with it set to 2, your first row will be ommitted)..

Comment: Apparently, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio, 15.0.18040.0. Thanks for the row tip!

Comment: Are you 100% sure your file is in CSV format?  In that it's COMMA separated, and not tab-delimited, space-delimited, or some other variation that doesn't actually involve commas?  I would open the file in Notepad just to make sure...

Comment: Facepalm. Yup, it was the way the CSV was saved. Jeez that's embarrassing. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 6):

Change FORMAT = 'CSV' to DATAFILETYPE = 'char'

or just remove the FORMAT = 'CSV' line as your file may not be RFC 4180 compliant.

```
BULK INSERT testingtable
FROM 'D:\TimeLords\data\db-test-file.csv'
WITH
    (FIELDQUOTE = '"',
     FIRSTROW = 2,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',  
     TABLOCK)
```

this has worked for me with this error.

Answer (score 3):

There's another potential culprit. I've been running BULK INSERTs into my SQL Server 2017 Express, and my syntax used FORMAT = 'CSV' and a ROWTERMINATOR of '\n' -- and it had been working fine for months.

I added a new column to the other system where I was routinely exporting data as a CSV, and when I went to do another BULK INSERT, it was failing because I had an extra column in my CSV that didn't line up with the columns in my SQL table. DOH! I just needed to add that same new column in my SQL db and all was well again. A stupid error on my part, but maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: I also had an extra column issue. There was an extra index column that caused the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Old post, but hey, every bit of knowledge helps.  You can also run into this issue if you use a CSV other encoding or types, e.g. if you save CSV for Macintosh or UTF-8 (as you can in Excel), this is not compliant with FORMAT = 'CSV'.  You can try other options like row terminator = '\r' while removing FORMAT = 'CSV' that did it for me for non-windows-based CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was an extra space on the end of the first row.