# Importing a CSV file that is semi-colon separated

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a CSV file that I downloaded from a fuel supplier portal. The data is delimited by semi-colons, has 11 lines of comments before the row that has the field headings on it.

[image]

has 3 lines of summary, and is Unix LF encoded

[image]

I used the SQL commands BULK INSERT to import another data file from another supplier :-

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[fuel_stagingShell]
FROM '\\server\path\dataimports\fueldata\Shell\results.csv'
WITH
(
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    FIELDQUOTE ='"',
    FIRSTROW=2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n',
    TABLOCK
)
```

Which is perfect as it imports the file in a split second.

However when I try BULK INSERT it won't work with this file. Yes, I can skip the header rows by altering FIRSTROW however there is the issue of the three rows at the end of the file. The LASTROW parameter on the BULK INSERT command requires a row number, which I do not know as the files are variable length.

I was thinking of importing the file in C#, skipping the 1st 11 rows, terminating when I get to the row that starts 'Total;' and matching the columns based on header names.

Is there a way I could import the rows of data, and split it into an array / POCO / something else, that is really easy and obvious way of doing it IF you know it's available?

I also have another file from this supplier, which is the same format except that there are half a dozen fields missing; which is why I was thinking that populating by matching on the column names, but I know that populating each property on each row might be a lot slower than other unknown methods.

**EDIT:** I replicated the issue so that I could edit this post with the error I was encountering with the file, and this guy gets the the same error message [("IID_IColumnsInfo") error with SQL Server BULK INSERT of CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952771/iid-icolumnsinfo-error-with-sql-server-bulk-insert-of-csv-file), so I replaced \n with 0x0a and added an arbitrary LASTROW parameter, as hinted at by @steve in the comments, and when I commented out the FIELDQUOTE parameter, it imported a load of rows.

I'm now thinking that I could pre-parse the file and count how many rows there are and building that into the dynamic SQL from my app. OR, modifying my staging table with longer varchar fields that will accept all the commentey bits at the end of the file and ignore them in the T-SQL stored procedure that validates the data and converts it into the transactions table.

Here is the T-SQL that I used:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[fuel_stagingDkv]
FROM '\\server\path\dataimports\fueldata\DKV\Results.csv'
WITH
(
FORMAT = 'CSV',
--FIELDQUOTE ='',
FIRSTROW=12,
LASTROW=5000,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a',
TABLOCK
)
```

Comment: Did you try to understand how bad are the performances if you try to determine the last good row. IE _int rows = File.ReadLines("filename").Count()_ After that you can subtract 3 to define the value for LASTROW in the insert

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorksCsvReader/ provides a flexible CSV reader, from [this old source](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader), which provides an `IDataReader` API on the data. This `IDataReader` can be provided to `SqlBulkCopy`, which provides access to the same TDS API that `BULK INSERT` uses.

Comment: Thanks @Steve I updated the post with further info. And your idea gave me inspiration. So, many thanks.

Comment: Why do not split last N rows using some command line utility before the import?

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you for that. I have bookmarked it to CintaNotes with a TODO tag, and I'll have a look at that. It looks interesting.

Comment: @serge I Think your comment has merit, I could write a command-line utility to split off the first superfluous lines and the 3 at the end. I could also verify that the column-headings are all there. Thanks.

Comment: Although pre-processing the file in C# might be the best idea, you still could import the whole lot in a staging table with just one column per line. You can manipulate/filter this staging table and use some kind of *string splitting* to get this into your final table(s).

Comment: Try [bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) - it is Microsoft's command line utility specifically designed for SQL Server to/from File loads.

Comment: Good call @knyazs. Looks interesting, and useful.

Comment: Please don't post images of sample data. Copy/paste the text directly into the question, and indent it or use `<pre>` blocks so it formats nicely.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks for your response, but as you can see from the image there is some data that I had to redact. I wasn't expecting anyone to download the data and try to recreate the issue, I was looking for pointers from someone who has encountered this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you need to skip a certain number of files at the bottom and you can enable `xp_cmdshell` to get the line count of the file, you could do something like this:

```sql
USE tempdb
GO

DECLARE 
    @filePath nvarchar(max) = '\\server\path\dataimports\fueldata\DKV\Results.csv'

DECLARE 
    @cmd nvarchar(1000) = 'type "' + @filePath + '" | find /c /v ""'
    ,@lastRow int

DECLARE @Output TABLE (
    Id int IDENTITY(1, 1)
    ,CmdOutput nvarchar(300)
)
INSERT INTO @Output ( CmdOutput )
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd

SELECT TOP 1 @lastRow = CmdOutput
FROM @Output 
WHERE
    CmdOutput IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY
    Id DESC


BULK INSERT [dbo].[fuel_stagingDkv]
FROM '\\server\path\dataimports\fueldata\DKV\Results.csv'
WITH
(
FORMAT = 'CSV',
--FIELDQUOTE ='',
FIRSTROW=12,
LASTROW=@lastRow,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a',
TABLOCK
)
```

Alternatively, you might be able to create a new file without the first and last lines using `xp_cmdshell`.